# :contains case insensitive solution does not work when text is replaced for highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this solution to make a custom case insensitive :contains

```
$.expr[":"].icontains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

The code that finds and replaced highlighted string

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
        var q = $(this).val();

        //hide all items
        $("ul#my_list").children("li").hide();
        //show matching
        $("ul#my_list").children('li:icontains("'+q+'")').show();
        $("ul#my_list").children('li').each(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).text());
        });
        $("ul#my_list").children('li:icontains("'+q+'")').each(function(){
            //var content = q;
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(q,"<span class='highlight_text'>"+q+"</span>")
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried multiple solutions for making contains case insensitive that you can find on google and SO but none of them work for me

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6r1q9rx2/5/

EDIT: It seems like it is Case sensitive - but will not highlight the matching text in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom function is working correctly. What isn't working is your replace function.
Your replace function isn't case-insensitive.

```
$(this).html(function(_, html){
    return html.replace(
        new RegExp("("+ q + ")", "ig"), // make a regex with capturing group
        "<span class='highlight_text'>$1</span>" // replace with the captured group
    );
});
```

The flags `i` and `g` are there to tell the engine to match case-insensitively and more than once, if available, respectively.

We are then capturing it in group 1, which we use in replace string as `$1`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6r1q9rx2/6/)

Comment: @maximl337 glad to have helped anyway :)